# How can i do "margin : width : height : auto; " in CSS?

Tags: css, variable-assignment

I tested it , dosent work.
Is there anyway i can assign a single value to many properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not unless you are generating the CSS source via a server side language, to my knowledge there is no 'variable' like support in CSS.  It's just text.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no way to do this with simple CSS**. But there are alternatives like [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) that allow you to do this and more.

Quote from Less css website:

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions. LESS runs on both the client-side (IE 6+, Webkit, Firefox) and server-side, with Node.js.

**Update**: Adding [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) thanks to @Michael Mior

Quote from website:

> Sass makes CSS fun again. Sass is an extension of CSS3, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool or a web-framework plugin.

Comment: No problem :) Personally I like to hand-craft my CSS and I don't usually like another layer of scripting in the way, but sometimes it can be rather handy.

Comment: Reading your comment above, I didn't realize LESS could run server-side. Going to have to look into that!

Comment: To be honest i know they exist but have not used any of them. I like to do it plain CSS too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can, however you can run your style sheet through the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and minify it if you're looking to alleviate bandwidth/parsing concerns.